# How to remove index.php within codeigniter on different port

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ports

removing index.php on codeigniter are found easy using .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but when needed to be on other ports? it doesn't work, why? and how to make it work?

in http://localhost:85/foldersite seems working, but when calling a controller it's not found, such as http://localhost:85/foldersite/mycontroller

yet the same .htaccess when deployed in server hosting these are just fine calling the controller because it didn't use any different port than 80 ..

and in file config.php and route.php already set as follows

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:85/foldersite';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
 $config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';


 $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: have u set your base_url in config.php

Comment: it was set to
 
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:85/foldersite';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: show your route.php also

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
     $route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: ok try set your base_url like this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/foldersite/';` and access url `http://localhost/foldersite/` and `http://localhost/foldersite/welcome/`

Comment: what is location of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: `.htaccess` located in root, and no, `http://localhost/foldersite/welcome/` is not working, but `http://localhost:85/foldersite/index.php/welcome/` does work and now it rewrite the url on the browser into `http://localhost/foldersite/`

Comment: `.htaccess` located in `http://localhost:85/foldersite/.htaccess`

Comment: is file type matter? I read somewhere it must be some certain type, because it seems it doesn't change when I modify the `.htaccess`

Comment: if is it so then by default ci has `.htaccess` file in application you can use it

Answer (score 0):

I think I just have the same issue as yours, and I managed to solve it just about couple of minutes ago.

Please consider to read this documentation page: [CodeIgniter URLs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html). Under the section of "Removing the index.php file" you'll be informed about Apache ***mod_rewrite enabled***.

Then, I implemented a tutorial from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) and it worked well. Just try it.

In addition, I have `.htaccess` content that exactly the same with yours. Except, I didn't modify any value from `$config['base_url']` and `$config['index_page'].`

I hope it helps.